# jquery removeClass leaves remaining properties in the style

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery ui draggable/droppable.

When I remove a class via `$(element).removeClass('test');`

```
.test {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

from an element it is indeed removed but when the display: flex is still applied as style on the element.

Why is that? I have `display: flex` set NOwhere via inline css.

Comment: Can you replicate it in jsFiddle ?

Comment: what events are bound to `.test` ? draggable? droppable etc . .

Comment: *"...but when the display: flex is still applied as style on the element..."* *Something*, somewhere, is applying it as an inline style (or, depending on what you're seeing, a different CSS rule is applying it). What you describe just won't happen otherwise.

Comment: Anyway you have to provide online minimalistic sample where your issue can be checked

Comment: @atmd yes the .test class is applied on a draggable element.

Comment: @Elisa Then you should disable draggable on this element

Comment: The funny thing is it does not always happen that display: flex remains after dropping the element somewhere. Most time it works and display:block is set as style.

Comment: @A. Wolff I also do: ui.draggable.detach() to be able to insert the dropped element into another html element. Else I can not insert it anywhere.